# Mobile Safari IOS indexeddb limit

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

I am trying to find out information on how much storage space can i use on safari for ios for 'indexedDb'.

I went to this site, on my iphone.
https://demo.agektmr.com/storage/

And i went to the section called 'IndexedDb'.

I filled there 50 files, each 5 mb each, which totalled 500 mb.

I read on the internet that once you hit 50mb of storage on safari, you get prompted, but nothing of that sort happened to me.

Can somebody help me with some info on the new storage limits criteria and eviction on safari for **indexedDB**. I believe the new IOS safari upgrade this october ,made old information obsolite.